# What's the correct way to use helpers to extend functionality in Django models?

Tags: python, django, oop, django-models, helper

I'm adding some extended functionallity to my models in Django. In order to not overload the model root interface (and file), i'm using some helpers as attributes of the model.

What i want is to group the methods and properties into this helpers, and what i want is something like:

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    downloads = DownloadsHelper()
    # ....
    pass

p = Product.objects.first()
p.downloads.files_count(p)
p.downloads.reset_permissions(p)
# ...
```

In order to not to have to pass the instance to the helper each time, I could use another approach.

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Product, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.downloads = DownloadsHelper(self)
        self.shipping = ShippingHelper(self)

p = Product.objects.first()
p.downloads.files_count
p.downloads.reset_permissions()
```

And finally, a more python-generic/conceptual way to do this stuff would be like:

```py
class Helper:
    def __init__(self, helped):
        self.helped = helped

class Helper1(Helper):
    attribute_name = 'helloing'

    def hola(self): print("hola")


class Helper2(Helper):
    attribute_name = 'goodbying'

    def chau(self): print("chau")


class Helped:
    def __init__(self):
        self._install_helpers()

    def _install_helpers(self):
        for helper in self.helpers:
            setattr(self, helper.attribute_name, helper(self))

class MyHelped(Helped):
    helpers = [Helper1, Helper2]

h = MyHelped()
h.helloing.hola()
h.goodbying.chau()
```

And the question is: ***Is this last approach a correct way /good practice to do the stuff from a pythonic-OOP and "Djangoid" point of view. Has this any problem?***

Thanks for reading!

Comment: The first method you described is in my opinion the most clear/maintainable. This way everybody that works with the code can quickly know which attributes/helpers your model has. The last way is a little bit confusing, there is no clear and fast way to check which attribute to call for the functions

Comment: thanks for answer. Ok, good point. Perhaps i could use a tuple list or a dict to assign the attrib name from the helped class. I agree it's a little bit of magic but i want not to repeat the  __init__() override in each model i use this feature

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you did not show the full complexity for your methods, but from what you showed it could be simplified a bit.

You could use "direct/simple" inheritance, and if you have a lot of methods then for organization you could maybe prefix the method names with `h1_` and `h2_` to indicate which helper class they are from:

```
from django.db import models

class Helper1:
    def h1_hola(self):
        print("hola")

class Helper2:
    def h2_chau(self):
        print("chau")

class MyHelped(Helper1, Helper2, models.Model):
    pass

h = MyHelped()
h.h1_hola()
h.h2_chau()
```

Would this simpler approach be sufficient for your specific needs?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The thing is, with this approach you need the `hX_` prefix in each method, and it extends the `MyHelped` root interface. I know *"flat is better than nested"* but in this case i preffer a nested one solution to avoid using the prefix in methods an etc.